# Quick Arc Length Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

> Let $f$ be the function satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=\frac{\ln(x+2)}{x^2+1}$ for $x>-2$. What is the length of the graph of $y=f(x)$ over the closed interval $[0,3]$?

I guess I'm a bit confused over what the length formula would look like in this example and how this formula would be evaluated. I understand that the length formula would look something like the following: $$L=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}\,dx,$$ but I'm not seeing an easy integration when this formula is plugged into the equation. I ended up getting something like: $$L=\int_0^3\sqrt{1+\left[\frac{\ln(x+2)}{(x^2+1)}\right]^2}\,dx.$$ I'm not really understanding how I'd go about integrating this or what an answer would look like here. Any help/clarification would be appreciated!

Comment: You should show us what you get when "this formula is plugged into the equation", and explain how you tried to find an "easy integration"; otherwise we are left to make unfounded guesses as to what troubles you encountered.

Comment: And if this makes your question not so "quick", that's fine.

Comment: Edits should've been made.

Comment: What makes you think that this is "quick" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you get the integral
$$\int_0^3 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\ln(x+2)}{x^2+1}\right)^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
Numerical integration yields $\approx 3.3197.$

Comment: Can I ask what numerical technique you used?

Comment: @Kevin Mathematica's `NIntegrate`. Read the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)